# Concrete5: can't send email from form

Tags: concrete5

I tried 2 SMTP servers, both times I can send test email from dashboard, but sending it from a form on front-end doesn't work. I use default form block and I tried to send email on different boxes. Is there any error logs that I can check? My C5 version is 5.7.5.8.

Comment: Got it after debugging `sendMail()` method. It sends from admin's email. So I've set my admin's email to noreply@example.com and it works now.

Comment: Error logs are in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`